# Android - How to check if BLE is implemented in my ROM

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a smartphone (Elephone p9) that supports bluetooth 4.0 but with my fitness band, that needs BLE, I can't pair. Even using a custom ROM it doesn't work. So how can I check if BLE is implemented via software? I suppose that I can't connect because the software is not managed to allow BLE protocols. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the model of your fitness band etc.

Comment: It's a xiaomi Mi Band. I can see it in settings->bluetooth (normally it shouldn't happen) but I can't pair with the app (the only way).

Comment: Did you try to establish a connection with an another Smartphone that has Android 4.4 as an OS and supports Bluetooth 4.0 ?.

Comment: Yes, I use the band with my nexus 7 (2012) with CM11 and it works, also I tried to pass a file from/to smartphone and tablet and it worked. If the band works with my tablet but not with my smartphone I think it could be a software problem.

Comment: What Android version you are using? BLE only supports Android 4.3 and above. In addition, BLE can not pair, your phone is device as center mode and your fitness band is peripheral mode. It's automatically interact in the raidus range. So, you must install application on your phone first for monitoring your fitness band.

Comment: I'm using KitKat 4.4.2. Neither with stock nor custom KitKat ROM it works. I think it could be a smartphone software problem that BLE is not implemented. But now I to know if it's implemented or not, or if it's another problem? I don't have another BLE device to test with my smartphone.